# Launch headless Chrome with an input type that supports hover

Tags: google-chrome, media-queries, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer to make e2e tests. It seems that headless chrome doesn't support the [@media (hover: hover)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/hover) media query (see [this issue](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/4820) on puppeteer github).

It seems likely that Chrome assumes the default input method for headless doesn't support hovering.

Does anyone know of a Chrome launch flag or some Javascript to get around this, please?

Comment: I've worked around this by: going to the page, extracting this CSS, transforming it to remove the hover media query, intercepting subsequent requests for the CSS and returning the transformed CSS instead. This works for my particular case.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that for now the only way to get the @media (hover: hover) media query in puppeteer is to run it with `headless : false`.

However you can emulate headless mode with [Xvfb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb).  There are a couple on examples of how to do that in the [Puppeteer-with-xvfb](https://github.com/nsourov/Puppeteer-with-xvfb) repository.